# Import Data from Big Query to Google Sheets automatically?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have a table in Big Query that is coming from Data Prep after some processing. Now I need to get this data to google sheets. I am currently importing the data from Big Query to Google Sheets using the "OWOX BI Big Query Reports" connector.It works fine till I have to refresh it again. All the new columns that I create in Google Sheets after importing the data get removed every time I refresh the data using the connector mentioned above.Is there a better way to fetch data from Big query without disrupting the created columns?

Comment: Are the 'added in' data fields some calculations based on the table data returned?  i.e.: Could you reform/redesign the query itself to do the calculations and return all your work by itself?  Or are you using data outside of what BigQuery knows about and can return?

Comment: Hey Sorry for the late reply. The calculation that I am doing is based on data which I am changing regularly, So, I have a sheet where I update the data and then that sheet is used in the calculation with BQ data.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Google Sheets wrong. Don't modify to sheet BQ creates, instead reuse the data in other sheet with IMPORTRANGE function, this way you create a copy of the data and columns created on this new sheet won't disappear.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340